# Which is the correct verb form with Who?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, relative-clauses, subjects

Sentence :

> She is one of those gifted writers who (turns, turn) out one best
>   seller after another.

My answer is: *turns*. 
As we are talking about *she,* singular third person.

But the correct answer says: *turn.*

Comment: I agree with and prefer your answer, but I think the examiner was trying to get "turn" to agree with the (numerous) "gifted writers", and therefore wanted you to use the plural.

Answer (score 2):

Here is your example sentence, with the relevant part in **bold**:

> She is one of those **gifted writers who turn out one best seller
>   after another**.

In this context, it is the gifted writer**s** (plural) in question who **turn** out bestsellers, and *she* is apparently a member of that club of bestselling writers.

So, **turn** it is.